# Laravel search column starts with the given word

Tags: php, laravel

I got a problem when search query using Laravel where and like.

```
$words = 'pa';

$query = Category::where(function ($query) use ($words) {
                $query->where('name', 'like', '%'.$words)
                      ->orWhere('name', 'like', $words . '%')
                })->pluck('name');
```

The result is:

```
[{Chocolate Spa, Zen Spa, Disco Party}]
```

The expected result is only `Party` .

I want it search name column starts with the given word not contain that words.

How can I achieve that search method?

Comment: just remove the `where()` method and it leaves you with: `$query->where('name', 'like', $words . '%')`

Comment: @iam-decoder I've tried your way. It return me empty.

Comment: there's no way, that query would result in something like `SELECT name FROM tablename WHERE name LIKE 'pa%'` which is a correct query

Comment: @iam-decoder can it because there is '<space> '  it return empty?

Comment: instead of `->pluck('name')` can you do `->toSql()` and paste in the output here?

Comment: select * from `merchant_branches` where `name` like ? and `merchant_branches`.`deleted_at` is null and `is_completed` = ? order by `sequence` asc limit 15 offset 0

Comment: oh wait a minute. it's because you have no records that begin with the letters `pa`

Comment: `disco party` isn't it second word start with 'pa'?

Comment: no, that's not how searching in mysql works, it will search based on the record. i.e. if the current record starts with pa then include it in the resultset, since the record as a whole starts with di it's excluded from the resultset.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work:

```
$query = Category::where('name', 'like', $words.'%')
    ->orWhere('name', 'like', '% '.$words.'%'))
    ->pluck('name');
```

Comment: there's no need for `ucfirst()` by default MySql will search in a case-insensitive manner

Comment: there's no need for that but do as you please :P